# How to extract original JString value from Listbox in Android Kitkat Delphi XE8

Tags: android, delphi, listbox, android-4.4-kitkat, delphi-xe8

I am making a test android multidevice application with Delphi xe8. I am attaching objects to the items in a listbox as follows:

```
 unit Unit1;

 interface

 uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes,  
   System.Variants,

  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics,    
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes, FMX.Dialogs,
 FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Layouts, FMX.ListBox,    
 Androidapi.Helpers;

 type
   TForm1 = class(TForm)
   ListBox1: TListBox;
   Button1: TButton;
   Button2: TButton;
   procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
   private
   { Private declarations }
   public
   { Public declarations }
   end;

     var
    Form1: TForm1;

    implementation
    {$R *.fmx}

    //this where I am Attaching objects to items
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
    str:string;
    jstr1:JString;
    begin
    str:='apple';
    jstr1:=StringToJString(str);
    ListBox1.Items.AddObject('fruit', TObject(jstr1));
    end;


    //this where I am extracting the jstring objects
    procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
     var
    jstr2:JString;
    str2:string;
    begin
    jstr2:=JString(ListBox1.Items.Objects[i]);
    str2:=JStringToString(jstr2);
    showmessage('the fruit of the day is '+str2);
    end;

   end.
```

The above code run ok and the jstring objects are attached to the items, however, when I want extract the jstring object that has been attached to the item, I do this:

```
 jstr2:=JString(ListBox1.Items.Objects[i]);
 //Above give me an AV: I get incompatible types TObject and JString

 str2:=JStringToString(jstr2);
```

The above code does not compile because of incompatible types TObject and JString. But yet if had attached a string as the object(instead of a jstring) and wanted to get back those string objects I could just do:

```
str2:=String(ListBox1.Items.Objects[i]);
```

This would work with regular strings. How do I solve this problem, attach and extract jstring?

Comment: FWIW, an AV is an access violation and means you are accessing memory that doesn't belong to the program, *at runtime*. I guess you meant a compiler error during compilation?

Comment: Your error message means JString is not a TObject descendant. You could perhaps store the address of the JString instead, but I am not familiar with what a JString is, exactly, so am reluctant to say for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a suggestion, and I can not check this (nothing installed here), but you could write a simple object type and store that (I put it in its own unit, which you then use in your form unit):

```
unit StringObjs;

interface

uses 
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes;

type
  TStringObj = class
  private
    FPayload: string;
  public
    constructor Create(const Payload: JString);
    class operator Explicit(const Obj: TStringObj): string;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Androidapi.Helpers;

constructor TStringObj.Create(const Payload: JString);
begin
  FPayload := JStringToString(Payload); // store string, not JString!
end;

class operator TStringObj.Explicit(const Obj: TStringObj): string;
begin
  Result := Obj.FPlayload;
end;

end.
```

And you use it in your form unit's implementation section like:

```
implementation

uses ..., StringObjs;

...

  ListBox1.Items.AddObject('fruit', TStringObj.Create(jstr1));
```

and reverse:

```
  MyString := string(ListBox1.Items[0] as TStringObj);
```

Note that a form is just a class, but one that the IDE knows about and can edit using the form designer. To declare other classes, do something similar as I do above. Read the [Delphi Language Guide](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Classes_and_Objects_Index) to learn more.

Comment: I put the type in its own unit and edited my answer. You should really learn about classes and how to declare and use them. See the link in my answer.

Comment: Declaration of 'Create' differs from previous declaration. I believe this is cause from 'const' missing the from first declaration(the one in the interface section). I added const to this as well to test if it would work but this resulted in the error I previously mentioned 'Undeclared FPayload'.

Comment: Edited: added a const in the declaration of Create. You could try to understand the code and then solve it yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much Rudy Velthuis. I have also followed your suggestion on reading "Delphi Language Guide". I never intended to be spoon-fed here but I am just glad for a solution. I am gonna try and edit/update the posts to include a complete question and solution, for those other noobs out there.